# error ora 904 en consulta multitabla

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Haciendo este ejercicio de sql me sal el error(las tablas department y jobs están unidas por otra llamada employees) :

> ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEES"."JOB_ID": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error en la línea: 52, columna: 77

- Obtenga sin  repetir  los  tipos  de  trabajos  (jobs)  que  realizan  en  los  departamentos  los  empleados.
- Liste  el identificador del departamento y el nombre del trabajo.

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT hr.departments.department_id,jobs.job_title
> FROM hr.departments,HR.jobs
> WHERE departments.department_id = employees.department_id 
> AND jobs.job_ID = employees.job_ID;
> ```

Comment: Y los nombres de los campos estan bien?

Comment: Si.el ejercicio esta sacado de la base de datos que trae oracle aqui lo puedes ver: https://docplayer.es/66482093-Caso-1-esquema-hr-oracle-recursos-humanos.html

Comment: Ah.. sera que falta la tabla employees en el from? Si no, como sabe a que tabla te referis.

Comment: Eso era, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pensaba que en el from solo se ponía las tablas de las que sacas campos.